# How to change app icon in different country IOS?

Tags: ios

I saw some old post about localize an app icon on IOS, I want to know if there are a way to do it now or if it still impossible? I didn't find anything about it

Comment: Why is this tagged flutter (or any of the other language tags)?

Comment: Because I think flutter users (and others) may have had this problem

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check the current country and to do so you need to **install** [react-native-localize](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize)

```
$ npm install --save react-native-localize
# --- or ---
$ yarn add react-native-localize
```

and the **usage** to get the country:

```
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

const country = RNLocalize.getCountry();
```

Now we need to change the icon programmatically using [react-native-dynamic-app-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dynamic-app-icon)
Since iOS 10.3 Apple supports alternate App Icons to be set programmatically. This package integrates this functionality as React Native module. **Android is not yet supported**.

**To Install:**

```
$ npm install react-native-dynamic-app-icon
```

**Mostly automatic installation**

```
$ react-native link react-native-dynamic-app-icon
```

**Usage:**

```
import AppIcon from 'react-native-dynamic-app-icon';
 
//check the language then:
AppIcon.setAppIcon('alternate');

//to get the icon name:
AppIcon.getIconName(result => {
  alert( 'Icon name: ' + result.iconName );
});
```